# Proving $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} = 2^n$ with Newton's Binomial Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm having a hard time proving this theorem from a textbook.

**Theorem**

For any integer $n \ge 0$, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} = 2^n$$

**Proof**

Take $x = y = 1$ in Newton's Binomial Theorem

**My work so far**

$$
x = y = 1 \\
\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k} 1^{n-k}1^k \\
= \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k} 1^n
$$

Then I tried using concrete examples
$$
k=0,\ \binom{n}{0}1^n \qquad \qquad \binom{n}{0} = \frac{n!}{0!(n-0)} = \frac{n!}{n!}=1\\
k=1,\ \binom{n}{1}1^n \qquad \qquad \binom{n}{1} = \frac{n!}{1!(n-1)} = \frac{n!}{(n-1)!}\\
k=2,\ \binom{n}{2}1^n \qquad \qquad \binom{n}{2} = \frac{n!}{2!(n-2)} \\
\vdots \\
k=n,\ \binom{n}{n}1^n \qquad \qquad \binom{n}{n} = \frac{n!}{n!(n-n)} =1\\
=1^n+\cdots+1^n
$$

How to prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $1$ to any power is $1$, that is, $1^{n-k}=1=1^{n}$ and so $$2^{n}=\left(1+1\right)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}1^{n-k}\cdot1^{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}.\text{}$$

Comment: wow...how did I not see this?

Comment: Also is it much harder proving by only using $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**.  The binomial theorem is an **equality**, not just an expression.  You have written down
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k} x^{n-k}y^k\tag{*}$$
and substituted $x=y=1$.  That's good so far, but the binomial theorem says that $(*)$ is equal to something else.  You need to remember (or look up) what this "something else" is, and substitute $x=y=1$ into that as well.